# Selective URL Cleaning with Regex

Tags: regex, sed

### The Problem

I have a datafile that looks like (except is a few million lines long):

```
((20091023,http://geocities.com/EnchantedForest/4217/index.html,http://rd.yahoo.com/footer/?http://alerts.yahoo.com/),1)
((20091023,http://geocities.com/EnchantedForest/Mountain/6235/mj.htm,http://rd.yahoo.com/footer/?http://paydirect.yahoo.com/),1)
((20090821,http://geocities.com/EnchantedForest/Cottage/6317/where_you_go.mid,http://geocities.com/EnchantedForest/Cottage/9999/index.html),1)
```

My end goal is to have a datafile that looks like:

```
http://geocities.com/EnchantedForest/4217,http://rd.yahoo.com/footer/?http://alerts.yahoo.com/,1
http://geocities.com/EnchantedForest/Mountain/6235,http://rd.yahoo.com/footer/?http://alerts.yahoo.com/,1
http://geocities.com/EnchantedForest/Cottage/6317,http://geocities.com/EnchantedForest/Cottage/9999,1
```

Note the unique pattern changing on line 3 above.

That is basically:

**Step One**: Find all URLs ending in a four digit number and end them there - so any URL string that ends in XXXX stops there (so we don't have individual files). This should be global.
**Step Two**: Clean it up, so that data is FIRST URL, SECOND URL, NUMBER

### What I've Tried So Far

My current solution is this:

`sed -E 's/([0-9]{8}),(http.+?[0-9]{4})(.+?,)/\2,/g'`

That is, it creates three groups in theory: - one group the first eight digit number (which I don't care about), the second group the URL up to the four digit number (which I do), and the third the rest of the string.

However, my results right now are like this:

`((http://geocities.com/EnchantedForest/Dell/3883,7)`

Which is close, but deletes the destination.

Any help or tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed` with multiple `s` commands:

```
sed 's/[()]*//g; s/^[^,]*,//; s~\(/[0-9]\{4\}\)[^,]*~\1~g' file
```

**Output:**

```
http://geocities.com/EnchantedForest/4217,http://rd.yahoo.com/footer/?http://alerts.yahoo.com/,1
http://geocities.com/EnchantedForest/Mountain/6235,http://rd.yahoo.com/footer/?http://paydirect.yahoo.com/,1
http://geocities.com/EnchantedForest/Cottage/6317,http://geocities.com/EnchantedForest/Cottage/9999,1
```